# Do I need uniform convergence for this exercise? (for composition of operators)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have the following exercise:  Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space and that $T_{n}$ & $S_{n}$ are bounded linear operators on $X$. Prove that if $T_{n}$ & $S_{n}$ are strongly convergent to $T$ & $S$ respectively then $T_{n} \circ S_{n}$ is strongly convergent to $T \circ S .$

But when I try to apply the definitions I am not sure how to follow. I know that if $S_n$ converges uniformly $S$, $||S_n(x)-S(y)||\leq \varepsilon $ if $||x-y||\leq \delta$ for any $\delta$, so I can put instead of $x$ and $y$, $T_n(x)$ and $T(x)$ respectivelly and that finishes the proof, but I dont have the uniform convergence, so I think that there should be another way to approach this, or do I need the uniform convergence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniform Boundeness Principle tells you that $\|T_n\|$ and $\|S_n\|$ are bounded. Now use the inequality $$\|T_nS_nx-TSx\|\leq \|T_n(S_nx-Sx)\|+\|(T_n-T)\|Sx\|$$ $$\leq \|T_n\|(\|S_nx-Sx\|+\|(T_n-T)Sx\|$$.